# /graphql and /graphiql endpoints returning 404

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-spring-boot

I am learning graphql and facing some issue in the local with hello-world level project code. Can you please help me on it.

Given the below details, I am able to build and run the application without any errors. But when I hit the urls localhost:8080/graphiql(in browser) or localhost:8080/graphql(in AltAir plugin), I am getting 404 as reponse (Whitelabel error page). Can you please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Details

1. I am using Java 17 as runtime.
2. Spring boot version : 3.2.1
3. Maven dependencies.

```
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

4. Query Class

```
@Component  
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    public String firstName() {
        return "Sankar";
    }  
}
```

5. Graphql schema file (query.graphqls)

```
type Query{
    firstName : String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is caused by incorrect dependencies for GraphQL support.

I used [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and it provides the following dependency in the `pom.xml` of generated project:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please, try to remove `com.graphql-java` dependencies and use the above instead or better generate a new `pom.xml` using Initializr for your project.

And one more thing to check for `graphiql` endpoint: in order to make it work, add `spring.graphql.graphiql.enabled: true` into `application.yml` of the project.

Comment: This didn’t solve the issue..!